# Picking Off Sum of Squares From Anova Table Keeping Variable Names in R

Tags: r, anova

This is an itch.  I can solve it but in cumbersome ways.  I presume there is a better way.  (there is not much info in `?aov`.)

I am trying to pick off the sum of squares from an anova into a vector, keeping variable names.

```
f <- y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xn
ss <- anova( aov( f ) )[,2]
```

gives me the SS, but loses the variable names.  (I could write code to reattach the names from the formula or the model attributes.)

```
as.data.frame(summary.aov(aov( f )))
```

leaves the variables space-padded, and also attaches a rowname, the anova attribute, etc., rather than just giving me a simple named vector.

is the double call to `*anova*(aov())` even the right direction?

or should I rewrite `summary.aov()`?

or should I just compute the numbers myself?

what is the recommended way?

Comment: have you tried `broom::tidy()` or `broom::glance()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler if you provide sample data, but here is an example with `mtcars`:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars.aov <- aov(hp~cyl+vs+am+gear+carb, mtcars)
mtcars.ss <- summary(mtcars.aov)
table <- data.frame(mtcars.ss[[1]])[, 2, drop=FALSE]
table
#                  Sum Sq
# cyl         100984.1721
# vs             985.7296
# am            6606.3122
# gear          8275.5360
# carb          5323.6281
# Residuals    23551.4970
```

Comment: thanks.  I marked it as a solution.  is there a built-in function/version that also divides these by the ssy?

Comment: Something like `cbind(table, Prop=table[, 1]/sum(table))`?

Answer (score 1):

Following @dash2's comment and @dcarlson's answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
mtcars.aov %>% tidy() %>% select(term,sumsq)
##   term        sumsq
##   <chr>       <dbl>
## 1 cyl       100984.
## 2 vs           986.
## 3 am          6606.
## 4 gear        8276.
## 5 carb        5324.
## 6 Residuals  23551.
```